# Problema useSelector para traer el estado inicial

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, redux, frontend

Tengo el siguiente componente Home que se renderiza ni bien carga la pagina, el cual no me esta trayendo el estado con useSelector, verifique en redux devtools y el state llega undefined, verifique la action, el reducer y en la accion hice un console.log para verificar que llegue info de la API, la info llega pero no esta haciendo el dispatch, no lo logro encontrar el error

COMPONENTE HOME: renderiza el estado inicial que deberia un ser array de objetos pokemon iterable para crear componentes CARD de cada pokemon, el estado inicial llega undefined apesar de usar async await

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { getPokemons } from '../actions';
import { GET_POKEMON } from '../actionTypes/actonTypes';
import Card from './Card';

export default function Home(){

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const allPokemons = useSelector((state) => state.pokemones);
    
    useEffect( () => {
        dispatch(getPokemons());
    }, [])

    function handleClick(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        dispatch(getPokemons());
    }

    return(
        <div>
            <Link to='/pokemon'>
                Atrapar pokemons
            </Link>
            <h1>Hora de atrapar pokemons</h1>
            <div>
                <select>
                    <option value="asc">Ascendente</option>
                    <option value="desc">Descendente</option>
                </select>
                <select>
                    <option value="all">Pokemons existentes</option>
                    <option value="creados">Pokemons creados</option>
                    <option value="tipos">Tipos de pokemons</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <button>Volver a cargar pokemons</button>
            {   
                allPokemons && allPokemons.map( p => {
                    <Card nombre={p.nombre}
                          vida={p.vida}
                          fuerza={p.fuerza}
                          defensa={p.defensa}
                          velocidad={p.velocidad}
                          altura={p.altura}
                          peso={p.peso}
                          tipo={p.tipo}
                          createdInDb={p.createdInDb}
                    />
                })
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```

REDUCER:

```
const initialState = {
    pokemones : []
}

function rootReducer(state=initialState, action){
    switch (action.type) {
        case "GET_POKEMON":
            return{
                ...state,
                pokemones : action.payload
            }
        default:
            break;
    }
}

export default rootReducer;
```

ACTION: En la action para revisar la conexion el back como prueba comente la linea 1 y 2 obteniendo la informacion que muestro mas abajo pero cuando las descomento al probar no retorna nada

```
export async function getPokemons(){
//linea1    return async function(dispatch){
        return await axios.get('http://localhost:3003/pokemons')
            .then(json => {
                console.log(json.data)
//linea 2                dispatch({type: "GET_POKEMON", payload: json.data})
            })
    }
}
```

INFO QUE LLEGA DE LA ACTION:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ERROR EN CONSOLA:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

IMAGEN DE REDUX DEVTOOLS

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Suena a que tu componente raiz (Home me imagino) no está conectado a tu store de redux.

(Ejemplo en inglés)
https://www.reactjstutorials.com/react-redux/10/redux-connect

`import { connect } from 'react-redux'`

  bla bla  
`export default connect()(Home)`

Comment: No es el error, el componente esta conectando el problema esta con el useSelector que el estado llega undefined, probe con la guia que pasas pero sigue sin conectar con el estado

Answer (score 0):

El problema de esto luego de leer mucha documentación fueron tres errores:

1. el reducer no estaba retornando nada por default
2. cambie createStore por configureStore
3. una ligera modificacion en la action

Comment: puedes subir la respuesta completa ?